# perl MongoDB batch_insert - can be done as an upsert?

Tags: mongodb, perl, batch-insert

perl, mongodb 2.4.9,  perl MongoDB 0.702.1

When I execute 
`$collection->batch_insert(\@array)`,
it works fine, but is there any way to make to do upsert in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why you want to do that.  If you have existing documents on your match criteria, you'll destructively overwrite them.

Nevertheless, with the v1.0.0 or later driver (and a version 2.6 or later mongod), if you add OIDs ahead of time, you can do something like this:

```
use v5.10;
use strict;
use warnings;
use MongoDB;
use MongoDB::OID;

my $mc   = MongoDB->connect;
my $coll = $mc->ns("test.foo");
$coll->drop;

my @docs = map { { _id => MongoDB::OID->new, x => $_ } } 1 .. 10;

# insert half as normal
my $res = $coll->insert_many( [ map { $docs[ 2 * $_ + 1 ] } 0 .. 4 ] );
say "Inserted " . $res->inserted_count . " docs";

# upsert whole batch
$res = $coll->bulk_write( [
    map { ( replace_one => [ { _id => $_->{_id} }, $_, { upsert => 1 } ] ) }
    @docs
] );

say "Matched " . $res->matched_count . " docs";
say "Upserted " . $res->upserted_count . " docs";
```

When I run that, I get:

```
Inserted 5 docs
Matched 5 docs
Upserted 5 docs
```

Comment: I realize you're on an older server and driver version.  Hopefully, this will give you some incentive to upgrade.  The v1.0.0+ drivers will work against mongod 2.4.9 and the code above should actually work, just not very efficiently, as it will do individual update operations (10 round-trips) instead of batching it into a single round-trip as it would for mongod 2.6+.